# a list of known convex functions?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces, non-convex-optimization

I am working on the development of novel optimization algorithm
where it DOES NOT suffer from the non-differentiability (cf. subgradient), which also works well in differentiable class of the objectives.

Now, I want to explore the behaviour of my algorithm. I only took relavant optimization courses like 4 lectures, but it does not necessarily mean I am super good or much experienced in this field.

So, is there any good article which $\mathbf{LISTS}$ interesting known convex objectives at a single sight for this purpose? Or should I manually try this and that based on my own experience so far?

Comment: You can search for ***"review article"***. Those are articles broadly speaking trying to summarize the current state of a topic. Well, if it is new anyway.

Comment: The search term you need is *benchmark problems*.

Comment: Such a method already exists. See http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_HTML/2013/04/3833.html. Also, a convex function on an open set is twice differentiable almost everywhere, so there is no practical difference between differentiability and subdifferentiability for convex problems.

Comment: @Serg , "There is no practical difference between differentiability and subdifferentiability for convex problems". It is hard to say so. I shortly checked your reference, clearly it is sublinear, which is a typical story. My goal is to achieve even superlinear.

Comment: @Robin. The method i linked to is optimal. This is as good as it gets without additional assumptions like strong convexity. Even linear global convergence is impossible to achieve for non strongl convex objectives.

Comment: @Robin. "It is hard to say so." If you are solving a convex problem with a method that somehow relies on using gradients instead of subgradients, then the probability of encountering a point of nondifferentiabilty is exactly 0, hence your method will work as it should with probability 1

Comment: @Serg, one day, I spoiled the setting of my algorithm to one of the lecturers in this topic. What he said was, the convergence rate of such algorithms are 'optimal' in a choice of estimate sequence but of course, we can push further and we only yet do not know such algorithms. It is wrong to believe that such sublinear convergence is the final dead end of convergence rate under given setting; non-differentiable.

Comment: @Serg, and I am looking for a good scenario to showcase my algorithm. I am currently taking a seminar in this semester, and in this seminar, a Path-following strategy for non-convex to convex relaxation arised. In his publication in this year (Max Planck Institute), I asked him. How many iterations do you have non-differentiability & differentiability? He couldn't say in detail because the convergence itself was not obvious in his publication (because of Path-following + non-differentiability).

Comment: @Serg. And he says, it is more probable to encounter non-differentiable cases on the development of Path-following. The point is, people tries to avoid non-differentiable cases because once then, we can use provably, and practically faster algorithms. For example, Quasi-Newton method if it has self-concordance. In your reference, Prof. Nesterov suggests an algorithm wish o(1/k) at maximum which is sublinear.

Comment: @Serg, if you can achieve superlinear in non-differentiable setting, will you use your reference or such unknown-method with superlinear convergence? Or you have such experience that the algorithms such as Nesterov's accelerated gradient algorithm or a Quasi-Newton method in practice, absolutely no harm to be applied on non-differentiable objectives?

Comment: @Serg. What if an objective has so many non-differentiable points? Can we still say the probability that an algorithm meets such point is still almost zero? And what if in future, we need such algorithm to optimize over an objective with so many non-differentiable points? The reason why non-differentiable objective is problematic is convergence rate of algorithms rely on choice of 'good' stepsize or/and directions in each step based on local heuristics. If there exist non-differentiable points, how much good such choices become less obvious. This is my motivation.

Comment: I can name 2 examples where people avoided non-differentiability to achieve better convergence, in this sense. [1] Support Vector Machine with l1-norm regularizer: You can achieve differentiable objective after fiddling with lagrangian dual. [2] Discrete energy minimization of Total variation denoising method: You play with auxiliary variable, convex conjugate, and with proximal. You end up with Projected-Gradient Descent. If the probability to encounter such non-differentiable iteration is zero, why do the people try so hard to avoid such situation?

Comment: @Serg, it's absurd to suggest that non-differentiability need not be considered in practice. Even Nesterov would say so, and _he did so in that paper_, in the very last subsection where he showed that smoothing improves performance dramatically.

Comment: @Michael Grant. Smoothing does not have anything to do with differentiability. Smoothing means making the function have Lipschitz continuous gradients instead of bounded gradients. That obviously may improve performance. However, there is no difference between using Lipschitz continuous gradients and Lipschitz continious subgradients, which is proven by the fact that the UFGM method uses only subgradients and achieves optimal performance on smooth problems.

Comment: I will continue this conversation with Nesterov I guess. I would call that a semantic nitpick at best. Certainly it’s no justification to discourage the OP from his study of an alternative. Heck there are multiple variants of accelerated gradients too.

Comment: @Robin, Surg does make a fair point in that any method you invent should be compared against the one he cited. When I was writing my dissertation I had a rule: “if I think of something cool, I had better make sure the Russians hadn’t thought of it first“. By “Russians” I meant specifically Nesterov and Nemirovskii ;-)